# rotate table (90 degrees) and stretch to fill whole page

Tags: tables, rotating, adjustbox

I'd like to rotate a table (90 degrees) and stretch it to fill whole page.

That's what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

I don't know how to stretch the height of the table therewith it fills the page (horizontally).

Is there any possibility to reduce the size of the font automatically if one text is wider than its cell?

edit: 
I probably didn't express myself very well. The table should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. For everyone having the same problem: (Probably you need to render twice)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
    \begin{tabularhtx}{\textwidth}{\textheight}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \interrowfill
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \interrowfill
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    \interrowfill
    \hline
    \end{tabularhtx}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Is it like this?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\hfill
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}    
  \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
  \end{tabularx}%
\end{adjustbox}
\hfill
\null

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `sidewaystable`. Set the column adjustment from `X` to `l`,`c` or `r` for wider text.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{|l|l|X|X|c|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
      1000000000000000000000 & 2000000000000 & 3 & 4 & 50000000000000 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 
  \end{tabularx}
\caption{A table}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I meant the height of the rotated table (the width in the document). The table should fill the page vertically and horizontally.