# Rotated table (90 degree in whole page) in two-column article

Tags: tables, rotating

I tried to make a table rotated in one page (according to ferahfeza's post in [rotate table (90 degrees) and stretch to fill whole page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170205/rotate-table-90-degrees-and-stretch-to-fill-whole-page)) but when I paste the same code in two-column article format, it didn't work properly, the table is placed on text (i.e, the table didn't take a new page but instead it printed on text in the same page)

How to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: "didn't work properly" doesn't let anyone debug your problem, please provide a small test file and say what error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rotating` package offers the `sidewaystable*` (and `sidewaysfigure*`) environment(s)  that work comparably to `table*` (and `figure*`)  and allow a table (or figure) to occupy both columns in a `twocolumn` environment. As you can see in the below example, the text fills up the page before the table and continues on the page after the table:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{|l|l|X|X|c|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
      1000000000000000000000 & 2000000000000 & 3 & 4 & 50000000000000 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
                \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
  \end{tabularx}
\caption{A table}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\hrule

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @leandriis and for the others too, the problem was solved