# Rotated a table in two-column paper

Tags: tables, tabularx, rotating, landscape

I have created a `Tabularx` in `two-column` article format. I have created it with using `landscape`. but now I want to rotate the page again. This is my table:

[image]

I want rotate that page with that table, I tried to copy the table in a new vertical page with using `sidewaystable`  like [that example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480376/rotated-table-90-degree-in-whole-page-in-two-column-article) but the format of my table was changed.
I won't  change the format and the structure of my table. any solutions?
I want to rotate all the page ( rotate a `landscape` page  with table ) like that :
[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,enumitem,ragged2e}
\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{%
  \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table} [htp]
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\centering
\scriptsize
\makegapedcells
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}

\begin{tabularx} {\linewidth}{ | wc{0.012\textwidth}  wc{0.020\textwidth} wc{0.030\textwidth}
                                 *{32}{|wc{0.011\textwidth}} |X|}  
\hline  
  \multicolumn{3}  {|wc{0.072\textwidth}|}   { \multirow[c]{11}{=}{\centering{ TextText}} }
  & \multicolumn{18}  {wc{0.198\textwidth}|}   {TextText} 
  & \multicolumn{9}  {wc{0.099\textwidth}|}   {TextText}
  & \multicolumn{5}  {c|}   {TextText}
  & \multirow[c]{11}{=}{{ \centering TextText }} 
\\
\cline{4-35}                
&&&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText} } } &
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText }} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
 \multicolumn{7}  {c|}   {TextText} 


                             &\multicolumn{2}  {c|}   {TextText}                & { \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{8.5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&

\\
\cline{22-30}

&&& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &
\multicolumn{3} {c|}   {TextText} & 
\multicolumn{2} {c|}   {TextText} & 
TextText & 
TextText &
{ \multirow[b]{6.75}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{6.75}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&

  & & & & &



\\
 \cline{22-27}
&&& & & & & & & & & &  & & & & & & & & & 
{ \multirow[b]{5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} }&
{ \multirow[b]{5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} } &
{ \multirow[b]{5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} } &
{ \multirow[b]{5}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}} } & &

 & &  & & & & &

\\

&&& & & & & & & & & &  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  & & & & &
\\

&&& & & & & & & & & &  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  & & & & &
\\
\hline

\multirow[c]{6}{=}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}}& 
\multicolumn{2}  {|c|}   {TextText}  &
\checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark  &\checkmark  & \checkmark  & \checkmark &\checkmark  & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & & & & & \checkmark & & & & & & \checkmark  & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & 

\checkmark & \checkmark  & 
\checkmark   &\checkmark   &\checkmark   &\checkmark   & \checkmark & 




\\ \cline{2-36}


& 
\multicolumn{2}  {|c|}   {TextText}  &
\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & & &\checkmark  &  & & & & & & & & & & & &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark   &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & 
&  
\\ \cline{2-36}

&

\multicolumn{2}  {|c|}   {TextText}   &
\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & & &\checkmark  &  & & & & & & & & & & & &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark   &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & 
&  
\\ 


\cline{2-36}


&
\multicolumn{2}  {|c|}   {TextText}  &
\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & & &\checkmark  &  & & & & & & & & & & & &\checkmark  &  &  & &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark   &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & 
&   
\\ 


\hline


\multicolumn{3}  {|c|}   {TextText} 
&\checkmark & &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & & &\checkmark &\checkmark  & & & & & & & & & &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark  &\checkmark &\checkmark & \checkmark & 

& 
\\ \hline


\multirow[c]{8}{\linewidth}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}}& 
\multicolumn{2}  {|p{0.135\textwidth}|} { \centering TextText TextText}  &
\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  & &  & & &  & & &\checkmark  & & &\checkmark  & & &\checkmark   & & &  &\checkmark  &\checkmark  &&\checkmark  &\checkmark   & & 

& 
\\ \cline{2-36}


&  
\multicolumn{2}  {|p{0.135\textwidth}|} { \centering TextText TextText}&
\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & & &  & & & & & & & & & & & &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & &\checkmark & &\checkmark  &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & 

& \\ \cline{2-36}


& 
\multicolumn{2}  {|p{0.135\textwidth}|} { { \rule  TextText TextText}}  & \checkmark & &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & &\checkmark & &  & & & & & & & & & & & &\checkmark & &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark  &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & &
 
\\ \hline 



\multicolumn{3}  {|c|}   { TextText TextText} &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark  & & & & & &\checkmark & & & & & & &\checkmark &\checkmark & &\checkmark & &\checkmark  &\checkmark &\checkmark &\checkmark & & 
\rule{0pt}{4pt}
\\ \hline

\multirow[c]{10}{\linewidth}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText TextText}}& 



\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{5}{=} {\hspace{0pt}TextText TextText}}
&
\multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt}Text } &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & & &  & & & &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark}& {\checkmark}& & & &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark} & & {\checkmark}&{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & &  
\\\cline{3-36}




&

\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{5}{=} {\hspace{0pt}   }}
 & \multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt}Text } &{\checkmark} & & {\checkmark}&{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & & &  & {\checkmark}& & & & & & & & & & &&{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark}  &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & & 
\\ \cline{2-36}



& 
\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{5}{=} {\hspace{0pt}TextText}}
&
\multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt} TextText} &{\checkmark} & & & & &{\checkmark} & & &  &{\checkmark} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark} & & & &{\checkmark} & &  
\\[5cm] \cline{3-36}



&

\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{5}{=} {\hspace{0pt}   }}
 & \multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt}TextText} &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & & &{\checkmark}  & & & & & & & & & & & & &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} &  & &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & & 
\\ \cline{1-36}

\multirow[c]{10}{\linewidth}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{TextText}}& 
\multicolumn{2}  {|c|} {\rule  \centering Text }  & & & & & &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & &  & & & & & & &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark}& & & & & & & &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark}  &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & &
\\\cline{2-36}


&
\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{10}{=} {\hspace{0pt}TextText TextText}}
&
\multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt} \rule Text } &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & & &{\checkmark}  & & &{\checkmark} & & & &{\checkmark} & & & & &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark}  &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} &{\checkmark} & & 
\\[5cm] \cline{3-36}



&

\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{5}{=} {\hspace{0pt}   }}
 & \multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt} \rule Text } &{\checkmark} & & & {\checkmark}& &{\checkmark} & & & {\checkmark} & & &{\checkmark} & & & & & & & & & &{\checkmark} & & & &{\checkmark} &  & & & & & &  
\\ \cline{3-36}

&
\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{5}{=} {\hspace{0pt}   }}
 & \multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt} \ruleABC}&{\checkmark} & & & &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark}& & &  & &{\checkmark} & & & & & & & & & & & & &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & & {\checkmark}& & 
\\\cline{3-36}

&
\multicolumn{1}{|p{0.080\textwidth}|} {  \multirow[c]{5}{=} {\hspace{0pt}   }}
 & \multicolumn{1}  {p{0.034\textwidth}|}{\hspace{0pt}\rule Text } &{\checkmark} & & & &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark}& & &  & &{\checkmark} & & & & & & & & & & & & &{\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & {\checkmark} & &{\checkmark} & & {\checkmark}& & 
\\\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}




\end{landscape}




\end{document}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A minimal working example would be really helpful here since there are several ways to rotate a table.

Comment: @leandriis I added my code

Comment: The code you posted is not compilable and results in a different output than the one you showed in your question.

Comment: You could try using the `lscape` package instead of `pdflscape`. However please be warned that rotating the page back to portrait orientation while keeping the table in  a landscape orientation will cause the text in your rotated cells to appear upside down.

Comment: Probably it would be better to just transpose the whole table and stick with a portrait table on a portrait page.